# Passing ajax request data from my service to a component (Angular 4)

Tags: ajax, angular

I have a service that retrieves data from a GET request and stores this data into two variables that I want to pass to my component - I can see all the data within the service I am just unable to retrieve this data once in my component.

When I call this.sidebarService.getMenuItems() in the console.log() it returns undefined - any ideas

// sidebar service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {
menu: any;
menuItems: any;
menuCategories: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {

  getMenuItems() {
    if (this.userService.getAuth() != null) {
        this.http.get('https://dev.mysite.com/api/calendar/auth',
            { params: new HttpParams()
                .set('token', this.userService.getAuth().__token)})
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log('data', data);
                if (data !== undefined) {
                    this.menuItems = (data.menuItems !== undefined) ? data.menuItems : [];
                    this.menuCategories = (data.menuCategories !== undefined) ? data.menuCategories : [];
                }
            });
    }
  }
}
```

// sidebar component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { SidebarService } from './sidebar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
 })

export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
 menu: any;
 menuItems: any;
 menuCategories: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService, private sidebarService: SidebarService) { 

    console.log('menuService', this.sidebarService.getMenuItems());
}

ngOnInit() {

}

objectKeys = function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from the`getMenuItems()` method

You should return an Observable :

```
...
return this.http.get('...
```